# WSDL Generator for C#

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Does anyone know of a good tool to generate the WSDL for a service contract written in C# (i.e. set of methods that are tagged as "[OperationContract]" using WCF)?  All the tools I've found work the other way around: create code stubs from a WSDL.  I don't want to have to hand-jam a WSDL file.  I've found tools for php and J2EE, but not C#.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is host the service with a base address setup, and then just hit it from a browser with "?wsdl" appended to the end.

Here's an example of a service configuration with a base address specified. Note this goes in the `<configuration><services>` element in your config:

```
  <service name="MyServiceName" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9000/MyService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9001/MyService"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="IMyService"
              bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding"/>
  </service>
```

Once you get it hosted, just go to `http://localhost:9000/MyService?wsdl` to see the WSDL definition.

Answer (score 9):

[svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702581.aspx) or just host it quickly and hit the MEX point :)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

a) **Download wsdl file and do below steps**:

i) Open visual studio command prompt as an administrator.

ii) Type below command:

wsdl.exe [path To Your WSDL File]

b) **With endpoint**:

i) Open Visual studio command prompt as an administrator.

ii) type below command:
    wsdl.exe http://localhost:9000/MyService